# Presto/Athena Union All Prepared Statements

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-athena, presto

How do you `UNION ALL` multiple prepared statements in Athena/Presto?

Lets say I have `PreparedStatement1` as:

```
aws athena create-prepared-statement --statement-name PreparedStatement1 --query-statement "SELECT colA1 AS col1, colA2 AS col2 FROM table1 WHERE category=?" --work-group primary
```

`PreparedStatement2` as:

```
aws athena create-prepared-statement --statement-name PreparedStatement2 --query-statement "SELECT colB1 AS col1, colB2 AS col2 FROM table2 WHERE category=?" --work-group primary
```

I would like to union both of them by

```
(EXECUTE PreparedStatement1 USING category1)

UNION ALL

(EXECUTE PreparedStatement2 USING category2)

ORDER BY col1
```

But it doesnt work.  I get an error

```
mismatched input 'EXECUTE'. Expecting: '(', 'LATERAL', 'UNNEST', <identifier>, <query>
```

Is it possible to do this in Athena/Presto?  I would like to union all more than 2 prepared statements

Comment: Based on the docs examples it seems not possible.